# How to display the postition absolute div as the position relative div?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent div "total" in which, there are two children divs namely, "some" and "box". When I click on the link in the div "some" (child-1), the "box"(child-2) must be displayed with width: 100%; and if I click on other parent link, the current "box" (child-2) must be hidden. Also, the paragraph tag must not be hidden when the click button is clicked(as in position: relative).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/38/) is the fiddle to work this out.

The following lines are the code I tried.

```
 $('.box').hide();
$(".click-btn").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').hide();
   $(this).parent().parent().children(".box").toggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this if it solve your problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/38/)

i added this

```
$('.box').hide();
$(".click-btn").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').hide();
   $(this).parent().parent().children(".box").toggle(1000);
});
```

add the css

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0px;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: But, the orange box must be in "100%" width.

Comment: Yeah. The code works. But, the paragraph tag must not be hidden. I mean, It must also slide down when the orange box slides down.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be putting each `.box` outside of the floating `.single` and reference them with an data attribute.

```
<div class="total">
    <div class="single">
        <div class="some"><a class="click-btn" href="#" data-box="box1">click</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="box" data-id="box1">Box 1</div>
</div>
```

And the box css

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  display:none;
}
```

If you set the display none in css you don't have to use `$('.box').hide();` on dom ready.

Since you hide all `.box` elements on click, the toggle function won't work. To toggle the box if you click the active link again you can use the `.not()` function of jQuery which will take out an element of the collection.

Alltogether the JS would look like:

```
$(".click-btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var boxId = $(this).data('box');
    var activeBox = $('[data-id="'+boxId+'"]');
    $('.box').not(activeBox).hide();
    activeBox.toggle(1000);
});
```

I'm using `e.preventDefault();` what will prevent the default browser action for clicking a link.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/40/

Comment: Great answer. But, the box is just getting displayed at the very bottom. I want it to be displayed at the bottom of each first child. See here http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/41/

Comment: To clarify your needs. Do you mean the `.box` should start left aligned to the `.single`? This is not the answer, it's just to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/42/

Comment: No, I want the script to work like the google image result page. When we click on an image, the image details should be shown below the particular image. like [THIS](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/).

Comment: Seems like a mix of a scroll to and a slide down animation whith some calculations for the size. I changed the code and made some comments to explain what it does. Have fun http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/44/